# Admin grid is redirecting to dashboard

Tags: magento2, admin, grid

Whenever **Add Secret Key to URLs** feature is enabled in admin, admin grid is redirecting to dashboard.

When it is disabled it is redirecting to correct URL(same page).

Please suggest how to pass secret key to URL.

`return $resultRedirect->setUrl('*/*/index');`

Comment: I dont understand what is your question but if you asking for "secret_key" to pass in url then you don't need to pass secret key from url it will automatically taken by magento's default way.

Answer (score 1):

you can try **setPath('frontname/controller/action')**

Answer (score 0):

You can give controller and action name in redirection

**return $resultRedirect->setUrl('route/contoller/index');**

Answer (score 0):

You form must have form key to allow submit data. Like this : [Click here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/6ea7d2d85cded3fa0fbcf4e7aa0dcd4edbf568a6/app/code/Magento/Backend/view/adminhtml/templates/admin/formkey.phtml)

Then you can redirect to dashboard using this below line :

```
$this->_redirect($this->_backendUrl->getStartupPageUrl());
```